# Trigonometric Functions—Arbitrary Angle Definition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Both the angle $\theta$ and the shaded triangle share the same adjacent and hypotenuse $-3/5$ since $\cos = \text{adjacent/hypotenuse}$. But, since we know $\cos(135^\circ)$ is not equal to $\cos(45^\circ)$, how should I interpret the shaded triangle angle?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Both the angle $\theta$ and the shaded triangle share the same adjacent and hypotenuse $-3/5$

This uses the definition of $\cos$ for the entire range $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ based on the unit circle, where the sides are considered as *signed* segments and, indeed, $\cos(\theta) = -3/5$.

> since $\cos = \text{adjacent/hypotenuse}$.

This, on the other hand, uses the geometric definition of $\cos\,$ for *acute* angles, where the sides of the right triangle are considered as *positive* magnitudes. In this case, $\cos(\pi-\theta)=3/5\,$, indeed.

Quoting from wikipedia's [Trigonometric functions - Right-angled triangle definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Right-angled_triangle_definitions):

> In ordinary Euclidean geometry, according to the triangle postulate, the inside angles of every triangle total $180^\circ$ ($\pi$ radians). Therefore, in a right-angled triangle, the two non-right angles total $90^\circ$ ($\pi / 2$ radians), so each of these angles must be in the range of $(0, \pi/2)$ as expressed in interval notation. ***The following definitions apply to angles in this $0 – \pi/2$ range***. They can be extended to the full set of real arguments by using the unit circle, or $\;\dots$

Comment: In other words, both acute and obtuse angles are right to use the definition of adj/hyp for cosine. The only key difference comes along if we apply it with degree. i.e. cos(45) and cos(135) ?

Comment: @youcanlearnanything Key difference is that the right-triangle definition uses the *positive* magnitudes of the sides and is only valid for acute angles, while the unit circle definition uses *signed* lenghts for the sides and is valid for any angle. This has nothing to do with degrees vs. radians or other angle measures, but with how `adj` and `hyp` are interpreted in each definition.

Comment: @dvix now I got it. thank you!